# How to insert an element in a sorted list in Java

Tags: java, list, class, sorting, insert

i have to create my own list in java. the elements(Person element) to be inserted must be sorted(low to high).
So i created a method compareTo to check the names of inserted Person.
The problem is with insert method. I wrote this code:

```
public boolean insert(Person p){
    PersonListElement element = new PersonListElement(p);
    boolean inserted = false;
    if(containsElement(p) == true){
        inserted = false;
        return inserted;
    }
    if(head == null){
        head = element;
        size = size + 1;
        inserted = true;
        return inserted;
    }
    PersonListElement position = head;
    PersonListElement prev = null;
    while(position != null){
        if(position.getValue().compareTo(element.getValue()) < 0){
            if(prev != null){
                prev.setNext(element);
                element.setNext(position);
                inserted = true;
                position = null;
            }
            prev = position;
            position = position.getNext(); //here i get pointerException prob.
        }
    }
    if(inserted == false && prev != null){
        prev.setNext(element);
        inserted = true;
    }
    size = size + 1;
    return inserted;
}
```

this is my method but is not finished. can you help me?

**EDIT:**

I tried to make a method for deleting elements too. I think that my code works for empty list, 1 size list and if the element is not in the end of list. But i dont know if my method deletes the last element:

```
public boolean delete(Person p){
    boolean deleted = false;
    if(size == 0){
        deleted = false;
        return deleted;
    }
    if(size == 1 && head.getValue().compareTo(p) == 0){
        head = null;
        deleted = true;
        return deleted;
    }
    PersonListElement current = head;
    PersonListElement prev = null;
    PersonListElement next = head;
    next = next.getNext();
    while(next != null){
        if(current.getValue().compareTo(p) == 0){
            prev.setNext(next);
            deleted = true;
            return deleted;
        }
        prev = current;
        current.getNext();
        next.getNext();
    }
    return deleted;
}
```

with this class i tested my code:

```
class SortList
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SortedList list = new SortedList();
        Person a = new Person("Alice", 10);
        list.insert(a);
        a = new Person("Al", 20);
        list.insert(a);
        a = new Person("Bo", 90);
        list.insert(a);
        p = new Person("Cin", 3);
        list.insert(a);     
        System.out.println(list);
        }
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of your class look like?

Comment: Not sure if your assignment allows for it, but Java has some nice [baked in features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for sorting and with your compareTo method you're half way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete the iteration as well as the insertion. Assuming you are implementing a linked list and you have a public `next` attribute at you `ListElement` class.

```
public boolean insert(Person p){
        ListElement element = new StackElement(p);
        boolean inserted = false;
        if(head == null){
            head = element;
            size = size + 1;
            inserted = true;
            return inserted;
        }
        ListElement temp = head;
        ListElement prev = null;
        while(temp != null){
            if(temp.compareTo(element) < 0) {
                    if(prev != null) prev.next = element; //Keep the chain connected
                    element.next = temp; //Insert you element before temp
                    inserted = true;
                    break; 
                }
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
        if(!inserted && temp == null && prev != null) { //You may want to insert it at the end of the list if no upper element is found.
                 prev.next = element; //Put it at the end.
                 inserted = true;
        }
       if(inserted) size = size + 1;
       return inserted; //This should be true in any case but I left it for the case you want to avoid inserting the element at the end if its place is not found.
    }
```

`ListElement.next` could also be a private or protected attribute and be accessed through a getter like `getNext()`.

I think you shouldn't return the `inserted` value since if the element can't be place before any other it should be placed at the end of the list and therefore always being inserted. That is, this code is a better implementation of a sorted list:

```
public void insert(Person p){
        ListElement element = new StackElement(p);

        if(head == null){
            head = element;
            size = size + 1;
            return;
        }

        ListElement temp = head;
        ListElement prev = null;

        boolean inserted = false;
        while(temp != null){
            if(temp.compareTo(element) < 0) {
                    if(prev != null) prev.next = element; //Keep the chain connected
                    element.next = temp; //Insert you element before temp
                    inserted = true;
                    temp = null;
                } else {
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!inserted && prev != null)
        { 
                 prev.next = element; //Put it at the end.
        }
       size = size + 1;
    }
```

Concerning your `delete` method, I think you are making things too complicated.
In your iteration you only have to keep two references: one for the previous element and another to the current.
If your first element is the one to be deleted then your `prev` reference will be `null` and you will have to update `head`. Otherwise, you will need to update `prev` next reference making it reference the element after `current`:

```
public boolean delete(Person p){
    boolean deleted = false;
    PersonListElement current = head;
    PersonListElement prev = null;
    while(current != null && !deleted){
        if(current.getValue().compareTo(p) == 0){
            if(prev != null) 
                prev.setNext(current.getNext());
            else
                head = current.getNext();
            deleted = true;
        } else {
        prev = current;
        current = current.getNext();
       }
    }
    if(deleted) size--;
    return deleted;
}
```

Comment: i cant undrstand this code here:
 if(prev != null) prev.next = element; //Keep the chain connected
                    element.next = temp; //Insert you element before temp
                    inserted = true;
                    temp = null;
                }
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
can you help me?

Comment: @usersuper `prev` keeps a reference to the node before `temp`. The `if` sentence you are asking about is used to check if there is a previous element and in that case you have to put your element right after it (by making its attribute `next` to reference `element`) and at any case right before `temp` (by making `element.next` to reference `temp`). Is it clearer now?

Comment: i accepted your answer. i have also one question about deleting elements. i tried to make it but i think that my code doesnt work if the element is at the end of list. my code is below

Comment: Ok i deleted my answer.

Comment: im not sure if your delete method work if i want to delete the last element because if(prev != null) { prev.setNext(current.getNext()); }.
then prev i think that maybe has a problem beacause current.getNext() isnt exists

Comment: @usersuper In that case `getNext` should return `null` which is assigned to `prev.next` thus becoming `prev` the last element which is what you want. That is why ,when iterating , your loops are like`while(current!=null)`

Comment: i want to ask you something about insert method. im testing my program so i put some println to check if my program runs for all situations but is giving me `Java.lang.NullPointerException` at line `temp = temp.getNext();` at else.

Comment: @usersuper `NullPointerException` is raised when you are trying to access a null reference. Can you edit you question posting an exact copy of the code you´re having problems with?